How to delete specific row/data with Pentaho REST API
I had a data in IRIS database that i want to delete using REST API in Pentaho. Any idea on how to do it? Can I do it with an URL that specifically hit the ID attribute (e.g. id=012345678-0123-012345) ????
Ive tried using Data Grid and REST Client and set the HTTP method to 'DELETE' but nothing happend... (Still new to this kind of stuff)
